# How to add sequential numbering for wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

Currently working on a site and trying to use sequential numbering just before the page titles on a wordpress menu but not exactly sure how to fit the < span> in without removing the page title and also how to get each page numbered sequentially. Current structure of what I am trying to achieve is below -

```
<ul role='navigation' id='navigation'>
<li class='page_item '><span class="number">1 </span><a href=''>About </a> </li>
<li class='page_item '><span class="number">2 </span><a href=''>Work </a> </li>
<li class='page_item '><span class="number">3 </span><a href=''>Contact </a> </li>
    <li class='page_item '><span class="number">4 </span><a href=''>etc. </a> </li>
</ul>
```

I started my PHP by using

```
<li><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?></li>
```

My CSS looks like this -

```
header ul li {
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

header .number { 
    padding-left: 4px;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    line-height: 1px; 
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shAUU/) 
I came across the Walker nav menu but I can't seem to comprehend it on my own.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change the <ul></ul> tag to <ol></ol>. The browser will automatically number each item. This also means that you can do away with the <span> elements

Comment: @jeff That works fine with the html markup but doesn't seem to work with the PHP I have above.

Comment: @user:2690782 See my answer to use CSS for styling

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't change the element type of  to  then you can change the format of the output using css.

```
#navigation ul {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li:before {
  counter-increment: section; 
  content: counters(section, ".") ": "; 
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM5Ey/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sticking the page number and title in an array, then looping through

```
$pages = array(
    1 => array(
        'title' => 'About',
        'url' => 'about.php'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'title' => 'Work',
        'url' => 'work.php'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'title' => 'Contact',
        'url' => 'contact.php'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'title' => 'etc',
        'url' => 'someFilename.php'
    )
);
foreach($whats as $name => $page) {
    printf("<a href='%s'>%s</a> ", $page['url'], $page['title']);
```

Then again, you could just use Jeff's idea and use `<ol></ol>` instead of `<ul></ul>` - which would make more sense and be a hell of a lot easier! xD